# WatchKit Extension上でペーストボードは動作しますか？

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, ios-app-extension, watchkit

WatchKit Extension上でペーストボードからNSStringを、取得すると１６進数になり、セットしても反映されないようです。

なにか制約があるのか、資料が見つからなかったので質問させていただきます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

NSLog( @"%@",pasteboard.pasteboardTypes);

NSString *str = [pasteboard valueForPasteboardType:@"public.utf8-plain-text"];

NSLog( @"%@",str);
```

---

LOG

2015-03-26 19:42:27.160 app WatchKit Extension[15192:1672729] (
    "public.utf8-plain-text"
2015-03-26 19:42:27.161 app WatchKit Extension[15192:1672729] <4a6f686e 20417070 6c657365 6564>